# PHP Choice between 2 options

Tags: php, if-statement, post

I am very new to the whole PHP scene since I just started with this at school, Mostly it has gone pretty good, I am learning a lot. I did however encounter some problems.

I need to make a calculater for KWU (electricity). There must be a choice for paying rate.
So far I came up with this:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
    $KWU = $_POST['KWU'];
    if ('tarief1') {
        $bedrag = 0.50 * $KWU + 200;
    } else {
        $bedrag = 0.75 * $KWU + 100;
    }

    $totaal = $bedrag * 1.19;
    echo "KWU = $KWU </br>";
    echo "Bedrag =  $bedrag </br>";
    echo "Bedrag incl. btw = $totaal";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<a href=\"energienota.php\">Nog een berekening</a>";
} else {
    ?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>winkelprijs</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h2>winkelprijs</h2>
            <form method='post' action=''>
                KWU <input name='KWU'></br>
                Tarief:</br>

                <select name="btwtarief">
                    <option value="tarief1" name="tarief1" id="tarief1">Tarief 1</option>
                    <option value="tarief2" name="tarief2" id="tarief1">Tarief 2</option>

                </select>
                <br>
                <input name='submit' type='submit' value='bereken'>
                <input name='reset' type='reset' value='wissen'>

            </form>
        </body>
    </html>

    <?php
}
?>
```

Now what I don't know is how to get the $tarief1 and $tarief2 choice working. Something with POST I suppose.
I hope someone can help me, also sorry for my bad English

Comment: If you want, you can just use javascript to display calculations, why user post values to just view calculations?Why not display without posting using js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this line:

```
if('tarief1')
```

to

```
if ($_POST['btwtarief'] == 'tarief1')
```

Btw: also you dont need `name` attribute for your `option` elements. They have `name` of `select` element:

```
<select name="btwtarief">
  <option value="tarief1">Tarief 1</option>
  <option value="tarief2">Tarief 2</option>
</select>
```

`id` attribute you may need, but I dont think so you will...

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew it was something like that, just couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Sorry I am knew to stackoverflow, thank you for telling me :)